# PVR meta data viewer for linux

Tags: video, pvr

I recorded some videos from my DVB-S device and it created some `.mpg` videos and a `.pvr` file for each; Also a `info3.pvr` file for each recording that keeps metadata info (record time,name,...).
I need to read this file (`info3.pvr`) and get those metadata.
The file is a binary file.

Is there any viewer application for this type of files for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lucky, my DVB-S PVR does not store any metadata, only channel name and time in the filename. So I had to write a script which looks up the TV programme on some website to find out what showed at the time.

If you're looking for generic tools to analyze binary files, you can try `hexdump` and `strings`.

`hexdump -C info3.pvr` would print the entire file so you can learn about its structure if any,

`strings info3.pvr` will simply print out readable ASCII strings contained in the binary file. For the manual approach (copy/pastaing name out of it) this might be sufficient if you're lucky.

For a more detailed answer unless someone just happens to know that particular file format you'd have to upload a sample file somewhere.